# How to increment data by week in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out the number of stores that had no sales for the last 4 weeks.  Because of the way the grid is structured in DevExpress, I need to show the weeks as Wk1, Wk2, Wk3, Wk4 as columns (the data in these columns would be the store count of stores with zero sales).

Right now my data has the Sale Fiscal Week as a row.  What I need it to look like is basically like:

```
Vendor        | Store  | City   | State | Category     | Wk1 | Wk2 | Wk3| Wk4
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
Prairie Farms | #16141 | Adrian | MI    | 2% Gallon    |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1
Prairie Farms | #16141 | Adrian | MI    | Whole Gallon |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0
```

instead of

```
Vendor        | Store  | City   | State | Category     | Sale Cal Wk | Sale Fiscal Wk
--------------------------------------------------------------------------    
Prairie Farms | #16141 | Adrian | MI    | 2% Gallon    | 2015-10-23  | 38
Prairie Farms | #16141 | Adrian | MI    | Whole Gallon | 2015-10-23  | 38
```

I have included my code which works so far.  I have a count(store) function as 'ZeroStore' in the final select statement to indicate the store as a Zero Sales store.

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF 1=0 
    BEGIN
        SET FMTONLY OFF
    END

    DECLARE @4WeeksAgo date
    DECLARE @Today date     

    SET @4WeeksAgo = DATEADD(day,-28,getdate())
    SET @Today = cast(GETDATE() as date)

    DECLARE @maxweek as tinyint
    SET @maxweek = case when (SELECT DGFiscalWeek 
                        FROM scans.dbo.DimDate 
                        WHERE CAST(Actualdate as DATE)=dateadd(dd,0,CAST(getdate() as DATE))) = 1 THEN 52 ELSE
                            (SELECT DGFiscalWeek FROM scans.dbo.DimDate WHERE CAST(Actualdate as DATE)=dateadd(dd,0,CAST(getdate() as DATE)))-1                             END


    DECLARE @LYear as int
    SET @LYear =  cast ((select  max(FiscalYr) from Scans.dbo.Scans)-1 as varchar(6))

    DECLARE @Year as int
    SET @Year =  @LYear+1

    CREATE TABLE #Initialize    
    (
       [Master Vendor] varchar (100),
       [Dairy Vendor] varchar (100),
       Store float,
       City varchar (50),
       State varchar(5),
       District int,
       Category varchar(20),
       [Sale Cal Wk] date,
       SaleYear int,
       [Sale Fiscal Week] tinyint,
       Units int,
       Sales money,
       Grade int
    )

    INSERT INTO #Initialize
        SELECT DISTINCT
            d.[Master Vendor], d.[Dairy Vendor], d.[Store],
            City, State, District,
            '2% Gallon',
            CAST(MAX(ActualDate) AS DATE) AS [Sale Cal Wk],
            DGFiscalYear,
            DGFiscalWeek,
            Units = 0,
            Sales = 0,
            Grade = 0
    FROM
        Scans.dbo.DGStores s
    FULL JOIN 
        Scans.dbo.DimDate dd ON s.State <> 'XX'
    FULL JOIN 
        Tableau.dbo.DollarGeneralDairyDistributors d ON d.Store = s.Store
    WHERE
        ((DGFiscalYear = @LYear AND DGFiscalWeek >= @maxweek) OR  
         (DGFiscalYear = @Year AND DGFiscalWeek BETWEEN 1 AND @maxweek))    
        AND d.Store IN (SELECT Store 
                        FROM DollarGeneralDairyDistributors)    
    GROUP BY 
        d.[Master Vendor], d.[Dairy Vendor], District, d.Store, 
        DGFiscalYear, DGFiscalWeek, City, State


INSERT INTO #Initialize
SELECT DISTINCT 
    d.[Master Vendor] ,
    d.[Dairy Vendor] ,
    d.[Store],
    City,
    [State],    
    District,
    Category = 'Whole Gallon',
    cast(max(ActualDate) as DATE) as [Sale Cal Wk],
    DGFiscalYear,
    DGFiscalWeek,
    Units=0,
    Sales=0,
    Grade=0
FROM
    Scans.dbo.DGStores s
FULL JOIN 
    Scans.dbo.DimDate dd
ON
    s.State <> 'XX'
FULL JOIN 
    Tableau.dbo.DollarGeneralDairyDistributors d
ON
    d.Store = s.Store
WHERE
    ((DGFiscalYear = @LYear AND DGFiscalWeek >= @maxweek) OR (DGFiscalYear = @Year AND DGFiscalWeek BETWEEN 1 AND @maxweek))    
AND
    d.Store IN 
    (SELECT Store 
      FROM DollarGeneralDairyDistributors)
GROUP BY d.[Master Vendor], d.[Dairy Vendor] ,District, d.Store, DGFiscalYear,  DGFiscalWeek, City, State


CREATE TABLE #Update
(Store varchar(15),
 Category  varchar(25),
  FiscalYr int,
  FiscalWk tinyint,
  Units     int,
  Sales     money)


INSERT #Update
SELECT DISTINCT Store,  Category, FiscalYr, FiscalWk,
    isnull(sum(isnull(SumUnits,0)),0) as Units,
    isnull(sum(isnull(SumSales,0)),0) as Sales
FROM scans.dbo.Scans sc
JOIN [Scans].[dbo].DollarGeneralDairyCategory  c
ON sc.ItemSku = c.ItemSku
WHERE   
FiscalYr >= @LYear  
GROUP BY[Store], FiscalYr, FiscalWk, Category

UPDATE #Initialize
SET Units = u.Units,
    Sales = u.Sales,
    Grade=100
FROM #Update u 
WHERE #Initialize.[Sale Fiscal Week] = u.FiscalWk AND #Initialize.SaleYear = u.FiscalYr 
    AND #Initialize.Store=u.Store AND #Initialize.Category = u.Category


SELECT *
, COUNT(store) AS 'ZeroStore' 
FROM #Initialize 
GROUP BY [Sale Cal Wk], [Master Vendor], [Dairy Vendor], Store, City, State, District, Category, SaleYear, [Sale Fiscal Week], Units,                   Sales, Grade
HAVING SUM( Units) = 0 AND [Sale Cal Wk] BETWEEN @4WeeksAgo AND @Today


    drop table #Initialize,#Update
END
```

Thank you very much for any input or help.

Comment: maybe you could prepare a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You need use PIVOT https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx